# android retrofit embedded query parameters

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

Android How to pass embedded query parameters using Retrofit... This is my GET METHOD Url:

```
localhost:5000/at_invitations?embedded={"invitee":1}
```

My Question is how to pass the embedded value`{"invitee":1}` as query parameter using Retrofit..

This is My Service Call declaration Code :

```
@GET("at_invitations")
Call<JsonElement> invitationLists(
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Query("embedded") String embedded

);
```

This My Service Call Code :

```
String token = App.getInstance().getToken();
    AppearancesService service = App.getInstance().getRESTClient().create(AppearancesService.class);
    Call<JsonElement> call = service.invitationLists(token, "{invitee:1}");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Success"+ response.body(););
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    });
```

This is error Line :(How to declare this value(`"{"invitee":1}"`))

```
Call<JsonElement> call = service.invitationLists(token, "{"invitee":1}");
```

Please help me.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("invite",1);
            String a=jsonObject.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here string "a" will have the format you want 
and your call should be like this

```
@GET("at_invitations?")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try this if it helps

**your Service Interface**

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("index.php")
Call<Model>getUserDetails(@QueryMap Map<String,JSONObject> stringTaskMap);
```

**Method to get details**

```
 public void getDetails(Map<String, JSONObject> task) {
        ServiceInterfaceApi interfaceApi = ServiceClass.getApiService();
        Call<Model> call = interfaceApi.getUserDetails(task);
        Log.v("@@@WWE", "Retrofit Request Method =  " + call.request().method());
        Log.v("@@@WWE", "Retrofit Request Body =  " + call.request().body());
        Log.v("@@@WWE", "Retrofit Request Url = " + call.request().url());
        Log.v("@@@WWE", "Retrofit Request executed = " + call.isExecuted());
        Log.v("@@@WWE", "Retrofit Request Headers= " + call.request().headers());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
                Log.v("@@@", "Response");
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.v("@@@", "Sucess");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.v("@@@WWE", "Failure " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

**Calling the method where required**

```
JSONObject taskM = new JSONObject();
        try {
            taskM.put("invitee", "1");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Map<String, JSONObject> taskMap = new HashMap<>();
        taskMap.put("embedded", taskM);
        getDetails(taskMap);
```